# Python Celery - Switch TaskRegistry implementation

Tags: python, dependencies, inversion-of-control, celery, code-injection

I'm wondering how I can change the Celery TaskRegistry implementation so that I can switch it with my own implementation. I wish to inject dependencies into tasks when they are created (e.g. when running the celery worker process).

I have tried:

```
from celery import Celery
Celery.registry_cls=MyCustomTaskRegistry
```

At the top before creating my app instance. But it does not seem to be picked up.

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

```
app._tasks=MyCustomTaskRegistry()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own registry like this

```
from celery import Celery

a = Celery()
print(a.registry_cls)    # gives original registry

from celery.app.registry import TaskRegistry

class MyCustomRegistry(TaskRegistry):
    pass

a.registry_cls = MyCustomRegistry
print(a.registry_cls)     # gives your custom registry
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. Doing app._tasks=MyCustomRegistry() was the solution.